How do I fix an error with importing a function from one .py script to another in VS code?
I am trying to integrate chatgpt to a discord bot but when I attempt to import a function, "chatgpt_response" from the openai.py script to discord_api.py it gives me the error

cannot import name 'chatgpt_response' from 'app.chatgpt_ai.openai' (c:\Users\USER\Desktop\my_ai_bot\app\chatgpt_ai\openai.py)

Here are the two scripts. Any help would be appreciated as I am a beginner in python.
#discord_api.py

from dotenv import load_dotenv
import discord
import os
from app.chatgpt_ai.openai import chatgpt_response

load_dotenv()

discord_token = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

class MyClient(discord.client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Succesfully logged in as:", self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(message.content)
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        command, user_message=None, None

        for text in ['/Mira','/mira']:
            if message.content.startswith(text):
                command=message.content.split(' ')[0]
                user_message=message.content.replace(text, '')
                print(command, user_message)

                if command == '/Mira' or command == '/mira':
                    bot_response = chatgpt_response(prompt=user_message)
                    await message.channel.send(f"Answer: {bot_response}")

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = MyClient(intents=intents)


#openai.py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import openai
import os

load_dotenv()

openai.api_key = os.getenv("CHATGPT_API_KEY")

def chatgpt_response(prompt):
    response = openai.chat.completions.create(
        model='gpt-4o-mini',
        prompt=prompt,
        temperature=1,
        max_tokens=10000
    )
    response_dict = response.get("choice")
    if response_dict and len(response_dict) >0:
        prompt_response = response_dict[0]["text"]
    return prompt_response


The given image is the set-up im using for modules etc
#run.py
from app.discord_bot.discord_api import client, discord_token

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.run(discord_token)

I tried making sure that the libraries are imported correctly and they seem to be working fine otherwise... Like I said before, I'm fairly new to python so I just need a little insight on the problem here. (And im trying to get the script to run the function after importing it)

Looking at the code you've shown here, that import should work.  Maybe you forgot to save your changes to the openai.py file?

@JohnGordon All of them are up to date with each-other

I tried to reproduce this error with following file structure (I suggest it's similar to yours):
--- run.py

--- app/
     |
    chatgpt_ai/ --- openai.py
    discord_bot/ --- discord_api.py

with following files content:
#run.py ------------------------------
from app.discord_bot.discord_api import client

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('success') 


# openai.py ------------------------------
print("openai init")
chatgpt_response = "345"

# discord_api.py ------------------------------
from app.chatgpt_ai.openai import chatgpt_response

print("discord init")
client = "123"

Import works fine. Program output:
openai init
discord init
success

But I got error like yours when I tried to change chatgpt_response name in openai.py file or when I left this file unsaved.
Make sure that your files are in correct directories, run.py is outside of app/ folder. Also check, that you have no spell errors in naming chatgpt_response in discord_api.py and openai.py (just ctrl+c & ctrl+v the name), and you have saved changes in all files (there is no white dot near file name in the top VSCode panel).
UPD. One more thought - try renaming your openai.py file. It is nemd just like library openai that you use, and here can be a names conflict. Try naming your file like openai_handler.py or sth like that. Don't forget to change the name also in discord_api import.
